# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode') - router.push({})

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vitest

I have recently upgraded my dependencies and now every time I click on my button to navigate to the next page (and thus triggers `router.push({ path: getBaseRoute("next-route") })` it throws the error `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'parentNode')`. I understand what the error means, but logging the `router`, I notice `router` isn't null. When I refresh the page however, the `router` succeeds in navigating me to the next page.

This is the part which causes the error:

```
    const router = useRouter();

    return await api
        .getByPostalCode(params)
        .then((response: PostalCodeResult) => {
            result.value = response;
            router.push({ path: getBaseRoute('next-route') });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            return Promise.reject(error);
        });
}
```

Removing the `router.push` part, removes the error as well. Logging the flow I can confirm I also get in the `then` successfully.

Dependency versions I am running:

```
"vitest": "^1.0.4",
"nuxt": "^3.9.1",
"nuxt-vite": "^0.3.5",
"@pinia/nuxt": "^0.5.1",
```

if any other dependency version is required, please say so.

Comment: The error message says that `parentNode` is the problem. Where is it?

Comment: As in, where the function gets called?

Comment: You didn't get a stack trace? The error is about `parentNode`, so you need to locate the statement/expression that has `parentNode`.

Comment: My stacktrace leads all the way back to the button which is being pressed. I could show you the complete flow from the very first button which instantiates it all the way to the OP.

Comment: It is the other end of the stacktrace that should point to an expression that has `parentNode`.

Comment: It would point to: http://URL/_nuxt/node_modules/.cache/vite/client/deps/chunk-AVXPPHYR.js?v=4d0e1dcd which would be parentNode: (node) => node.parentNode, However this is something I have no control of (as you can see it's a node module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to resolve the error you should put a `<div></div>` around the `NuxtLayout`. See the following as reference: https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/13309